# on gdb, LoadLibrary mets sti instruciton and singals SIGILL

Tags: c, winapi, dll, gdb, mingw

In my program I load a dll during runtime with LoadLibrary. Every thing works ok when running in release mode.

But when I try to run program in debug mode, the load library stops with SIGILL, debugger shows it stops on sti instruction.

I also tried to link dll during program load by direct call from dll.
But I get SIGILL during program load.

I am using mingw48 shipped wit qt5.
I am not interested in debugging that dll, only to debug the other, self written part of code.

I as I found so far sti/cli instructions are only in privileged code. As I understand code running in gdb is not privileged.

I have already tried to ignore signal with `::signal(SIGILL, SIG_IGN);`

Gdb command `handle SIGILL pass nostop noprint` helps here but I would like to know if my program SIGILLs elsewhere

What I realy need is to load that library in some non debug mode while the rest of program is being debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that library itself handles the SIGILL, but GDB is catching it before library has chance to resolve it.
I see no better option than    handle SIGILL pass nostop noprint.
Only hint is to use create local .gdbinit file so debug session does not stop.
For qt it is:

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
QT_OUTDIR = $$OUT_PWD/debug
gdbinitfile.target = $$QT_OUTDIR/.gdbinit
gdbinitfile.commands = echo handle SIGILL pass nostop noprint > $$gdbinitfile.target
}
```